# Generic coverter for fields in class

Tags: c#, generics

Here is a simple implementation of generic method that get value from array in class and cast it to a type.

```
    private T GetReferenceFieldValue<T>(ReferenceRow referenceRow, string fieldName)
    {
        var referenceField = referenceRow.field.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == fieldName);

        if (referenceField != null)
        {
            //Dictionary for actions with types
            var typeActions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>
                {
                    { typeof(DateTime), () => { return DateTime.Parse(referenceField.Item.ToString()); } },
                    { typeof(int), () => { return int.Parse(referenceField.Item.ToString()); } },
                    { typeof(string), () => { return referenceField.Item.ToString(); } },
                    { typeof(Guid), () => { return new Guid(referenceField.Item.ToString()); } },
                };

            var fieldValue = typeActions[typeof(T)]();

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, typeof(T));
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> referenceRow.field
> ```

The `field` name does not comply with the C# naming convention for public members that should be PascalCase. It should also probably be `Fields` since it's apparently a collection.

---

> ```
> typeActions
> ```

Consider changing its name to `convertTo` which in this context makes the usage more natural:

```
var fieldValue = convertTo[typeof(T)]();
```

---

> ```
> Func<object>
> ```

Consider using a parameter rahter then using closures. That makes the usage even clearer.

If you define it as

```
Func<object, object>
```

and the lambdas as

```
{ typeof(DateTime), x => { return DateTime.Parse(x.ToString()); } },
```

you can call it with

```
var fieldValue = convertTo[typeof(T)](referenceField.Item);
```

---

> ```
> if (referenceField != null)
> ```

Avoid unnecessary nesting. You can use a postive condition `== null` and `return` right away if it's `nulll`.

---

> ```
> return (T)Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, typeof(T));
> ```

This is redundant. The converted value has already the target type. It just needs to be casted and because the `ChangeType` boxes the value anyway, you might as well do it yourself like this:

```
return (T)(object)typeActions[typeof(T)]();
```